# Which event to use on a <h:inputText> to cover all changes

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I want to update an icon immediately while the user enters a value into a <h:inputText>.

I have the following makup:

```
<h:inputText id="listprice" value="#{mybean.listPrice}">
    <f:converter converterId="mybean.convertPrice"/>
    <a4j:ajax event="keyup" render="infoIcon" />
</h:inputText>
```

Everything works fine if I realy **type** the value!

However if I revisit the page and start typing in the value, my firefox offers me a list of values from my previous sessions to select and now if I select one of those values with the mouse **I don't get an event!**

I understand this, because there is no keyup in this case. So I bound another event handler like this:

```
<h:inputText id="listprice" value="#{mybean.listPrice}">
    <f:converter converterId="mybean.convertPrice"/>
    <a4j:ajax event="keyup" render="infoIcon" />
    <a4j:ajax event="mouseout" render="infoIcon" />
</h:inputText>
```

... and tied all kinds of events from "onchange, to onmouseout" with no sucess.

So how to I cover this "event of selecting from a browser-sugesstion-list" immediatelly ?

Comment: how about `event="change"` (not onchange)

Comment: You can try using the onchange event.
A code example can be found [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937925/jsf-can-inputtext-invoke-a-method-inside-managed-bean-when-i-press-the-return-e?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want values from user previous sessions you can use attribute ***autocomplete="off".***

Otherwise you can use onmouseup event, it works for me.

Comment: onmouseup does not work for me either, however autocomplete="off" is excatelly what I'm using as a work around. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This may be a known bug and a workaround is suggested here: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=584166&start=0&st=0&sk=t&sd=a

The linked post is very old and is discussing Firefox v2 so there's a fair chance that it is no longer relevant, but if you get a chance to try the suggested workaround perhaps you could let us know if it works or not.